# Autoload files by patterns instead of listing each file

Tags: .info

Drupal's "autoloading" requires one to include the files in [files[] declarations in the .info](https://drupal.org/node/542202) file.

When there are a lot of files, this becomes:

- A large, huge, list.
- Hard to maintain.

Is there a way to e.g include with patterns. Say `lib/*.php`?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I'm not sure why you would have an unmanageably large list of files though?  Is this for an installation profile/distro (just out of interest)?

Comment: No. It is an ecommerce-ish module, with lots of external sources (Services) a statemachine and quite some OOP. right now, I have ~30 classes, but, from experience, I know that will grow and shrink a lot during development.

Comment: Remember that autoloading works only with files containing classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [mpdonadio](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpd) about implementing `hook_registry_files_alter()`, but I would rather use the following code.

```
function mymodule_registry_files_alter(&$files, $modules) {
  $include_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes';

  foreach (file_scan_directory($include_path, '/\.inc$/') as $file => $object) {
    $files[$file] = array(
      'module' => 'mymodule',
      'weight' => 0,
    );
  }
}
```

By default, [file_scan_directory()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7) checks the content of any sub-directory; if you want to avoid it, you can replace the `foreach()` loop with the following one.

```
  foreach (file_scan_directory($include_path, '/\.inc$/', array('recursive' => FALSE)) as $file => $object) {
    $files[$file] = array(
      'module' => 'mymodule',
      'weight' => 0,
    );
  }
```

The code can also be simplified by removing the `foreach()` loop, and using a callback that `file_scan_directory()` calls for each file.

```
function mymodule_registry_files_alter(&$files, $modules) {
  $include_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes';
  $array = &drupal_static('mymodule_add_files', array());
  $array = $files;

  file_scan_directory($include_path, '/\.inc$/', array('recursive' => $recursive, 'callback' => 'mymodule_add_files'));
}

function mymodule_add_files($uri) {
  $files = &drupal_static('mymodule_add_files', array());

  $files[$uri] = array(
    'module' => 'mymodule',
    'weight' => 0,
  );
}
```

Replace `$recursive` with `TRUE` if you want the function looks for files in the sub-directories for the directory passed as argument, or with `FALSE` in the case you don't want that.

Comment: Yeah, forgot that Drupal has a built-in for scanning dirs.  Always better to use the Drupal functions, even when they are simple one-line wrappers around PHP functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially use [hook_registry_files_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_registry_files_alter/7) along with the PHP directory functions.  Something like

```
function foo_registry_files_alter (&$files, $modules)
{
  $include_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'foo') . '/includes';

  if ($handle = opendir($include_path)) {
    while (($entry = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE) {
      if (preg_match('/\.php$/', $entry) === 1) {
        $files[$library_path . $entry] = array(
          'module' => 'foo',
          'weight' => 0,
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is untested, but the idea is to use scan an "include" directory for PHP files, and then tack them onto the array that the class registry uses for the autoloader.  This should work, but I can't remember exactly what `readdir()` returns, so you may need to adjust the paths a bit.

Answer (score 1):

[xautoload](http://drupal.org/project/xautoload) does that since quite a long while :)

Doc page: http://drupal.org/node/1976198

This should be enough for your case:

```
dependencies[] = xautoload

; Only look at the top level directory
files[] = lib/*.php
```

or

```
dependencies[] = xautoload

; Scan the top level and deeper.
files[] = lib/**/*.php
```

More stuff, if you need it:

```
; Ignore the top level, only scan deeper directories.
files[] = lib/*/**/*.php

; Ignore the top level, scan second level, ignore deeper levels.
files[] = lib/*/*.php
```

Good luck with that!